# Center a sticky div while it has justify:start?

Tags: css, viewport, sticky

I'm trying to achieve what the hero section of https://www.moritzpetersen.com/ does.

1. First, there seems to be a container (up to the CTA button) that is roughly 70vh high and has flex center content.
2. This is followed by another container (banner and mockup screen). When scrolling this container appears to be 100vh high, position: sticky and flex center so that the mockup screen is centered in the viewport.

Now something magical happens: When increasing the height of the viewport by resizing the browser window of the mockup screen of the second container remains visible in the viewport. This would not be possible if the second container were set to flex center as the space above and below the mockup screen would increase with an increase of viewport height. Thus it seems that the second container is set to justify start so that the mockup screen remains in the 20vh viewport that are left after the first container. But if that is the case I don't see any way to center the mockup screen in the viewport when scrolling with position: sticky.

Can anyone help?

I tried different approaches, using position: sticky and altering flex properties but there is no way I can keep the mockup screen visible in the viewport with increased viewport height while having it centered after scrolling.

Code Example:

```css
.hero {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 85vh;
  min-height: 42rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.hero-block {
  width: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
  background-color: #000;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: #f5d311;
}

.work {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.work-block {
  display: flex;
  width: 50rem;
  height: 20rem;
  padding-bottom: 40%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #d07aff;
}

.work-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  display: block;
  height: 300vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navbar"></div>
  <div class="hero">
    <div class="hero-block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="work-wrapper">
    <div class="work">
      <div class="work-block"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```